# Failed to debug via android device

Tags: android, driver, device

Why when I tried to launch my App via Android device, I got an error like the picture below 
[image]

Comment: reinstall device drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1º Reinstall drivers.

2º Activate Debug Mode ( Device )

3º Allow USB Debug

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lN1N.png